# trigger css keyframes only when class is added

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you click `button 2` you will see the `animation` run. However, when I make a change to the button using another function (checking the checkbox to show. hide the button), the animation runs again as if it were being pressed again.

How do I prevent the animation from triggering every time a separate function makes changes to the button? i.e on `toggle` or `show/ hide`?

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });

  $("input").on("change", function() {
    $(this)
      .closest("section")
      .find("#hide")
      .toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  background: silver;
}

button.active {
  background: green;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 300ms none;
  animation: bounce 300ms none;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <button>
  Button 1
</button>
  <button id="hide">
  Button 2
</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by toggling `display` property.
You might use another way to hide an element, e.g.:

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });

  $("input").on("change", function() {
    $(this)
      .closest("section")
      .find("#hide")
      .toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  background: silver;
}

button.active {
  background: green;
  animation: bounce 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.hidden {position:fixed; top:-150%}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.7);
  }
  50% {
     transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <button>
  Button 1
</button>
  <button id="hide">
  Button 2
</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `$.toggle` and `$.hide` set the `display` to `none`, all previous computed styles are discarded. So when this rule is removed afterward, the CSS engine will set a new `animation` rule, and start it from the beginning.

To avoid that you have multiple choices.

The first one is more JS oriented, and allows you to keep jQuery's method.

You need to have a logic in your button's click handler that will add a particular class only intended to set the animation. This way, the animation will get triggered only in this click event. By listening to the next `animationend` event, you can wait until your animation finishes, and from there remove the animation class:

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() { // only on button's click
    $this = $(this);
    // already active, return early
    if($this.hasClass('active')) return;
    // add both classes
    $this.addClass("active bounce")
      .one('animationend', function() { // when the animation is finished
        $this.removeClass('bounce'); // deactivate
      });
  });

  $("input").on("change", function() {
    $(this)
      .closest("section")
      .find("#hide")
      .toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  background: silver;
}

button.active {
  background: green;
}
button.bounce {
  -webkit-animation: bounce 300ms none;
  animation: bounce 300ms none;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <button>
  Button 1
</button>
  <button id="hide">
  Button 2
</button>
</section>
```

An other solution, maybe cleaner even though less jQuery friendly is to hide your element with other means than display none:

```
button.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("active")
  });

  $("input").on("change", function() {
    $(this)
      .closest("section")
      .find("#hide")
      .toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  background: silver;
}

button.active {
  background: green;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 300ms none;
  animation: bounce 300ms none;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
/* our hidden class */
button.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.7);
    transform: scale(0.7);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <button>
  Button 1
</button>
  <button id="hide">
  Button 2
</button>
</section>
```